# Express res.redirect() returning HTML rather than redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a call to my backend using an XHR request. Here's my frontend code:

```
var makeRequest = function(method, url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.send();
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  makeRequest('GET', '/spotify', console.log);
});
```

Here's my backend code for the `/spotify` route:

```
const Querystring = require('querystring');

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const queries = Querystring.stringify({
    client_id: process.env.SPOTIFY_ID,
    response_type: 'code',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/redirect'
  });
  res.redirect(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${queries}`);
};
```

Rather than redirecting, the HTML of the page being redirected to is returned from the XHR function. If I go to the route without clicking the button (via something like `localhost:4000/spotify`) it works as I want it to and I'm redirected.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Seems you are using backticks here? => res.redirect(`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${queries}`);

Comment: What difference might that make? Tried it without and get the same behaviour.

Comment: @DavidR — [That's not a problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal and expected behaviour.

A redirect means "The content you asked for is over here".

A redirect **does not** mean "The browser should load this URL as a new page".

You made the request from XMLHttpRequest. This means that XMLHttpRequest will handle the response. The server said it should get the content from some other URL, so XMLHttpRequest fetched that URL and provided the data in its `responseText` object.

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense. Is it possible to do a backend redirect if the request comes from an XHR request then? I'd like to redirect a few times on the backend before passing the data back to my XHR callback.

Comment: I have no idea what "a backend redirect" is. There's no way to detect a request from XHR. You could put extra data in the request to tell the server to go down the other path.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to do document.innerHTML = xhr.responseText if the statusCode is in the 300's?

Answer (score 0):

That's just because XHR handles redirects as every normal request.
If you try to take a normal XHR request (in your JS Console) to a page that responds with a redirect, the browser will redirect you to that page, it doesn't matter if that was a XHR request or a normal request.